# Facebook SDK for iOS , on iOS 4.0 device

Tags: ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook SDK documents indicates that this SDK will work on iOS 4.0 and later. Then I tested their Scrumptions sample on a iPhone 3GS iOS 4.0 device. But it seems this application doesn't work. It keeps showing me the login screen although I logged in.

Then I debugged and noticed `FBSessionState` always returns`FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed`. 
It never returns `FBSessionStateOpen`.

What could be the reason? However when I run this in iOS 5.1 emulator it works fine.  Is it because SDK doesn't support iOS 4.0 or some other issue?

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare both

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation;
```

and

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

?

The first one is iOS 4.2 and later so if your device is running with a version prior 4.2,the second method will be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just like saulobrito stated. I got this problem myself and solved it by implementing this method in the app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; ;
}
```

You don't have to implement the handleOpenURL