# ios6 facebook integration login always FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed never opens

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

this question is very similar to [Facebook SDK for iOS , on iOS 4.0 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924651/facebook-sdk-for-ios-on-ios-4-0-device), but as I cannot make comments there, I open a new question. I think the questions are not the same:

When trying to update the facebook integration of my app to facebook 3.1 I am not getting the facebook session to open the sessionStateChanged Callback always ends up in FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed. in my setup I have the callback in my appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    //    return [self.session handleOpenURL:url]; 
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

but it is never called! shouldn't it get called? I followed the facebook documentation and call

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions", nil];
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                                 state:state
                                                                 error:error];
                                         }];
}
```

I also tried

`openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions` with `nil` for the permissions as in the facebook tutorial example with the intention to reauthorize for the publish_actions permission later. same result: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed again.

I even tried calling

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore;
    ACAccountType *accountTypeFB;
    if ((accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init]) &&
        (accountTypeFB = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook] ) ){

        NSArray *fbAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeFB];
        id account;
        if (fbAccounts && [fbAccounts count] > 0 &&
            (account = [fbAccounts objectAtIndex:0])){

            [accountStore renewCredentialsForAccount:account completion:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult renewResult, NSError *error) {
                //we don't actually need to inspect renewResult or error.
                if (error){

                }
            }];
        }
    }
```

before trying to open the session, but I never get it open on my ios6 device (iphone 4s). in the app I am asked for the permission, but then nothing goes on because the session is always having the state FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed! my callback for the session state is

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
            NSLog(@"FBSessionStateClosed");
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            NSLog(@"FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed");
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:FBSessionStateChangedNotification
     object:session];

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"facebook Hinweis"
                                                        message:@"facebook Login nicht möglich, bitte versuchen Sie es erneut."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Facebook session error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

with the facebook 3.0 on ios 5 I never had an issue so my facebook app is set up correctly. I would really appreciate any help wchich enables me to just open the facebook session, did not think to run into these problems with facebook 3.1 and the docs are not helping me at this point, thx

Comment: please note: it works perfect on ios6 and ios5 simulator from Xcode. only on the real device it won't open as described. the device has facebook enabled, the facebook installed and is connected to a facebook account.

Comment: I have a weirder problem than you, on the iphone is working, on ipad is not. The same code, it's an universal app, there are no conditions on the fb logic.

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you resolved it already?

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem, and it was because I forgot to implement

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

in my AppDelegate

Comment: That was the fix I needed. Too easy to overlook. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

While JohnG's answer is correct, that particular delegate method has now been [deprecated](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW15). The correct delegate method to use [is this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aopenURL%3asourceApplication%3aannotation%3a):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Placing that in my application delegate solved the issue for me.  Without this, the iOS 6.0 native login would work but the Facebook app login would fail.

Comment: Thanks @jzn, but in my case the delegate method u mention is not being called. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @dredful That callback is only used for the Facebook App/web view fallback login. If you are using the iOS 6 login it will never get called, as the app is never put into the background. Which way are you logging in?

Comment: Thanks @jzn. Our app was using the Facebook App login. If the user does not have Facebook installed, then the web view is launched and then it fires. Odd thing: If user is iOS6 Settings logged int Facebook, SDK will not log in regardless of any other scenario. I will post to SO today.

Comment: Oh boy. Have you seen that in Facebook's docs, "Configuring XCode" section,  there is no mention of this method? It used to be...

Comment: @AndreiStanescu It's still a required function, it's just in a separate part of the instructions. Take a look at step 2D in [Authenticate Using Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/#step2)

Comment: True. I must have skipped that. "Authenticate using Facebook Login" is a tricky name... makes me think that I want to implement Facebook Login in my app as a primary user authentication method. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. If the user hadn't a Facebook account configured in the System Preferences the Facebook login dialog appeared and everything worked fine. But if the user had an account configured in the device I was always having a `FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed` error.

It has nothing to do with `handleOpenURL:url` because in the "native login flow" for iOS 6 or greater there is no fast-app-change. So your app never goes to background and the URL redirection is not needed.

The problem was solved configuring the Facebook app. You need to enable the "Native iOS login" section and put the bundle ID of your app. If your app is not already in the Apple Store I'm afraid you need to set the sandbox mode to ON. Once your app is published in the Apple Store I think you need to put the sandbox mode to OFF and set the Apple Store ID in the Facebook configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Even i can't comment so writing it as answer .
I am not sure , let me analyze potential reasons
1) you said: "but it is never called! shouldn't it get called?" -- for

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation
```

to get called , in the info.plist file , url scheme should be set properly i.e go to URL types-->Item0-->URL Schemes--->Item 0 the value here should be fbAPPID i.e fb append with your actual facebookappID [FacebookAppID could also be present in the info.plist or hard coded in code].

2)You said:
"sessionStateChanged Callback always ends up in FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed"

In the sessionStateChanged switch method check the state of session and if it  created or createdTokenLoaded then try to open the session.

Note:[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions ....] which is a static method will create a new session and is set to FBSession.activeSession  where as openWithCompletionHandler is an instance method which can work only if the session is already created .

```
    case FBSessionStateCreated:
    case FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded:{
        [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            //handle the updating of views according to the sate of session 
        }];
        break;
```

Comment: thx ravi! luckily I am allowed to comment on my own questions ;) regarding the call to openURL, yes, my url scheme within info.plist is configured correctly, I rechecked it and also had never problems with it under the 3.0 sdk! I just tried adding the FBSessionStateCreated and FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded with the openWithCompletionHandler to the switch statement in sessionStateChanged as you recommended, unluckily still the only value state gets is always FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed and thus the openWithCompletionHandler block gets never called :(

Comment: does the openURL always get called normally? and any hints why the same code works beautifully on the ios6 simulator (for which I configured the facebook framework in the settings identically with the same facebook account)?

Comment: OpenURL is always called when some other app tries to invoke your app using the url scheme (fbappid://... in info.plist , your app registering the scheme with iOS)  .i guess simulator doesn't have native app and uses safari or web view for authentication . This could be reason for different behavior b/w device and simulator. Also see that u are not closing the session on sending it to background .

Comment: I am not sure of the reason but i read on SO that openActiveSession is creating problems (due to the order when the active session is set) and so people created own session and set it as active session and then calling openWithCompletionHandler .

Comment: the simulator for ios6 DOES have the native framework configurable the same way as on the device and safari login is not used if it is configured, that's why it puzzles me so much that it works there but not on real device! regarding background handling I'm only handling 
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive]; in applicationDidBecomeActive and [FBSession.activeSession close]; in applicationWillTerminate as the facebook docs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with JohnG, with the additional caveat of:

Note that if you have multiple cases inside of `handleOpenURL:`, you can filter for:

```
if ([sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.facebook"] ||
    [sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.Facebook"]){
  //Do Stuff
}
```

It's weird, but I was able to replicate on multiple devices the `sourceApplication` coming back as "Facebook" and "facebook".

Comment: [[sourceApplication lowercaseString] isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.facebook"] will do the job

Answer (score 0):

On FB SDK 3.5, You can kill the token with this:

```
    [[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy defaultInstance] clearToken];
```

Comment: and you can log into your facebook developer account and then kill your token on this page...really useful for testing:

        [link]https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Graph API Explorer