# FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed every time I try and log into my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Hi this returns a state of FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed every time I run it.  I've checked my bundle name, URL setting etc and all cool. In fact face book knows i've authenticated against the app.  However ever time I call openWithCompletion my session fails !!

```
     [appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
        switch (status) {
            case FBSessionStateOpen:
                NSLog (@"Open");
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosed:
                NSLog (@"Closed");
                break;
            case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                NSLog (@"Failed");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        [self updateView];
    }];
```

I have created this in the app delegate that also get called successfully, but always returns false:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK how weird.  I took the FB SDK login example used my FB app code and bundle ID and it worked.  I then reran mine and it worked ?  Maybe FB server replication took a bit of time ?  No idea but it goes now ....

Answer (score 12):

Did you try this in your app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I had a similar issue got it fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661104/ios6-facebook-integration-login-always-fbsessionstateclosedloginfailed-never-ope)